# How to make accumulator an Empty Set of Int in Scala foldLeft?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, set, foldleft

I currently have a Set in Scala of size greater than 1 :

`val x = BitSet(19, 49)` and 
`val z = HashMap(49 -> HashSet(5, 6, 9, 13, 3, 8, 4), 19 -> Set(5, 9, 14))` of type `Map[Int,Set[Int]]`

I am trying to construct a `Set[Int]` having all values associated to the element in `Set x` using foldLeft, the end result would be: `HashSet(5, 6, 9, 13, 3, 8, 4, 14)`, but I am not able to correctly set the accumulator as a `Set[Int]`.

I am not using `x.foldLeft(Set(0))((acc, elem) => acc.union(z(elem)))` and then removing the element `0` from the final set.

I tried `x.foldLeft(Set.empty)((acc, elem) => acc.union(z(elem)))`

```
type mismatch found   : 
Set[Int]     (in scala.collection.immutable) 
required: Set[Nothing] (in scala.collection)
```

I even tried creating an empty `Set[Int]` as a variable and using it in fold expression but It also did't work. I cannot keep `Set(0)` as initial value of the accumulator since it might occur as an actual value.

Comment: `x.foldLeft(Set.empty[Int])` should work. BTW, do you need to do it using `foldLeft`?

Comment: Thank you, It worked. I am not sure why I was trying to reinvent the wheel. Yes, I need to use foldLeft since these sets might grow large. Any other approach with better performance?

Comment: Nah, I had other solution in mind but it was actually slower. BTW, `z(elem)` is unsafe it would be better to do `z.getOrElse(key = elem, default = Set.empty[Int])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for 1 minor mistake, the code is perfectly fine. `x.foldLeft(Set.empty)((acc, elem) => acc.union(z(elem)))`

There are ways to fix this:

```
1. x.foldLeft(Set.empty[Int])((acc, elem) => acc.union(z(elem)))
2. x.foldLeft[Set[Int]](Set.empty)((acc, elem) => acc.union(z(elem)))
```

TL;DR

If we dig deeper int the scala code this is the signature of `foldleft`

`def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B`

There are 2 parts of this curry function, where first one`def foldLeft[B](z: B)` while the second part contains `op` which will be applied during iteration.

Let's understand how the compiler will infer the Generics.
`x.foldLeft[?](Set.empty[?])` here in the `Set.empty` question mark will be replaced with a default `Nothing` but in `ops` function the parameter `acc` has the type of Set[int]. This will cause a type mismatch.

To fix the compilation issue, either we need to supply the type parameter in the `Set.empty` or explicitly provide type before the foldLeft so that `Set.empty` the correct type will be infrared by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, both approaches fixed the mismatch.